# Use Same Event For Multiple JLabels

Tags: java, events, netbeans, jform

I am using NetBeans and am wanting to use one MouseClick event for 3 JLabels. My issue is that in the Designer when I click on Properties - Events, NetBeans wants to add a custom event handler to my code like this

```
private void jLabel4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

But all I want is for the Designer to let me use this custom event as my OnClick event for all labels.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
   JLabel label = (JLabel) mEvt.getSource();
   Icon icon = label.getIcon();
   //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(label, icon);
}
```

Comment: In the netbeans property editor, you can set the event handler directly, look under the "Events", you can either select an existing method (via the drop down) or create new ones (and manage them).  My personal recommendation is, it's time to leave the form editor behind and start coding by hand, this way you could just a single instance of a `MouseListener` and assign it that instance to each label

Comment: When I look under events I do not see my custom event as an option to use.  I only used the form editor bc I was unsure on setting the positions of my JLabels so I used the form editor to control the position and set them up nicely.  Looking under events only shows jLabel4MouseClicked to use.

Comment: Netbeans will only let you use the one events it's created (sorry, my confusion).  I would direct ALL your labels through that one event handler and then call your method from it, if you don't want to implement the functionality within the netbeans provided handler ... yet another reason to abandon the form editor

Comment: Ah - NetBeans is incapable of doing what I wanted.  Thank you for that info!  Guess it's time for me to play more with the "placement" of controls using IntelliJ so I can better learn how to do this

Comment: Remember, Netbeans (like IntelliJ) is just an IDE - I just don't use any of the form designers, they are not worth the time or frustration